# UK visa application returned by UPS before the decision was made

Tags: visas, uk

On June 19, 2018 my biometrics were collected at the USCIS immigration office in Revere, Massachusetts, but the application document were returned by UPS saying that the document can't be picked up in this type of envelope. Is it possible to send my application again in another envelope? Can you suggest me what can I do next to continue my UK visa application?

Comment: What type of envelope were the documents in?

Answer (score 5):

The [instructions](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/usa-apply-for-a-uk-visa/apply-for-a-uk-visa-in-the-usa) stated at the time that you should *post* your application (*post* being British English meaning *mail* in American). The guidance has since been updated and now says *mail* instead of *post* to reduce this confusion.

Use the United States Postal Service, Priority Mail or Priority Mail Express services.

Answer (score 5):

Did you use a [UPS envelope](https://www.ups.com/ru/en/help-center/packaging-and-supplies/supplies-forms/express-envelopes.page?)? The [FAQ from VFS Global](https://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/USA/frequently_asked_questions.html), the official processor for UKVI, explains how to do it as follows:

> If you purchased Round-trip Courier, you will affix the Submission UPS Shipping Label to the front of a UPS envelope. Inside the UPS envelope, you will include the printed copy of Return UPS Shipping Label, along with a printout of your checklist (if you applied on AccessUK) or a printout of the front page of the application form (if you applied on Visa4UK), along with your supporting documents. Please make sure to check the address on the shipping label affixed on front of the package since applicants mistakenly affix the Return UPS Shipping Label to send applications to the UKVI. Make sure the “SHIP TO: “has the address of UK Visa and Immigration office in New York/Sheffield as per your application type.